# Кодирование массива категориальных признаков в машинном обучении

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

Есть один столбец категориальных признаков (они закодированы 1,2,3,4,5), этот столбец может принимать несколько значений через запятую, например 
3,5.

Как преобразовать данный столбец по типу OneHotEncoder, только чтоб единицы проставлялись по значениям из массива, MultiHotEncoder (multiple hot encoder) ?

Как сделать это в python при помощи sklearn.

Comment: Приведите небольшой (3-5 строк) пример входных и выходных данных

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример:

```
In [14]: df
Out[14]:
  Col1  Col2                     Col3
0    C  33.0  [Apple, Orange, Banana]
1    A   2.5           [Apple, Grape]
2    B  42.0                 [Banana]

In [15]: from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

In [16]: mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()

In [17]: df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df.pop('Col3')),
    ...:                           columns=mlb.classes_,
    ...:                           index=df.index))

In [18]: df
Out[18]:
  Col1  Col2  Apple  Banana  Grape  Orange
0    C  33.0      1       1      0       1
1    A   2.5      1       0      1       0
2    B  42.0      0       1      0       0
```

Comment: большое спасибо! это действительно решает мою проблему.